# Cannot get link to display in js quiz results

Tags: javascript, wordpress

In the "explanation" section of the quiz answers, I'm trying to include a link but the html always gets stripped out.

This is at line 446 of the .js file:

```
$('#quiz-form').append('<p class="special" id="special_' + key + '" ><strong>Correct answer(s): ' + answer + '</strong> » Explanation: ' + special + '</p>');
```

I've tried every variation of linking and escaping I can find but they all just show the title as plain text. Here's what I've tried, these are currently in the explanation sections for each of the first six questions:

1. `special: "<a href='URL'>title</a>"`
2. `special: "<a href=\'URL\'>title</a>"`
3. `special: "<a href=&quot;URL&quot;>title</a>"`
4. `special: "<a href="\&quot;URL\&quot;">title</a>"`
5. `special: "<a href=\x22URL\x22>title</a>"`
6. `special: "<a href=\x27URL\x27>title</a>"`

Unfortunately, there's no way to link directly to the answer page - you have to get the first six questions wrong in order to see the explanation as shown in the screenshot.

ETA: Now I'm encoding the angle brackets and the entire `a href` string is showing as text.

```
special: "&lt;a href='URL'&gt;title&lt;/a&gt;"
```

is showing as

```
<a href='https://www.lawlessfrench.com/vocabulary/introductions/'>Introductions</a>
```

Progress?

https://www.lawlessfrench.com/quizzes-and-tests/proficiency-test-1/

https://www.lawlessfrench.com/wp-content/themes/cassie/js/proficiency-test-1.js

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hm, worked for me in a jsFiddle.  Maybe the problem is that your jQuery version is so old, or maybe the browser or jQuery are trying to prevent XSS attacks.

Try changing

```
special = value.special;
```

to

```
special = $('<span>' + value.special + '</span>').html();
```

Comment: Tried that, no joy.

Comment: Try stripping out code until it works; this will help you narrow it down to find the error.  Maybe other javascript files on the page are conflicting.